# I need help spliting a vector into seperate vectors of all possible lengths

Tags: r, split

I have a large data frame that contains a bunch of different environmental variables. I have already split these into individual vectors and sorted them in descending order. I need help figuring out how to take each vector (length 171) some with NA values, and break it into all possible vectors of length greater than 1.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
vect_1 <- rnorm(10, mean = 12, sd = 2)
vect_1 <- sort(vect_1)

Group_by_2 <- split(vect_1, ceiling(seq_along(vect_1)/2))
Group_by_3 <- split(vect_1, ceiling(seq_along(vect_1)/3))
Group_by_4 <- split(vect_1, ceiling(seq_along(vect_1)/4))
…
Group_by_10 <- split(vect_1, ceiling(seq_along(vect_1)/10))
```

however I want/need to do this recursively:

I've tried variations of the following as a start, knowing that this does not address my need for each result to be stored in a separate list:

```
N <- 1:length(vect_1)


for(val in 1:N){
  split(vect_1, ceiling(seq_along(vect_1)/N))
    print(vect_1)
}
```

the above only gives me 1 list that splits the vector into a single list of length N

```
x <- 1:10
for(i in x){
  split(vect_1, ceiling(seq_along(vect_1)/x[i]))
    print(vect_1)
}
```

this gives me 10 lists, all of which are identical and all are of length 10.

so in summary what I need using a vector of 1-10

```
[1] - 1,2,3,4,5
[2] - 1,2,3,4 [2] - 5
[3] - 1,2,3 [3] - 4,5
[4] - 1,2 [4] - 3,4 [4] - 5
[5] - 1 [5] - 2 [5] - 3 [5] - 4 [5] - 5
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Not clear about the question

Comment: @Citizenkain101, your explanation is opaque.  You say that you want all splits for a vector.  But your _in summary_ example for a vector of 1-10, seems to only be some of the splits for 1:5

Answer (score 1):

If you use my `multicool` package, then you can generate all the integer partitions of an integer *n*.

```r
vect_1 = rnorm(10, mean = 12, sd = 2)
vect_1 = sort(vect_1)
n = length(vect_1)

library(multicool)
Comps = genComp(n)
```

If you look at these, you'll see that some have splits into vectors of length 1 which you don't want, so we can throw these out

```r
Comps = Comps[unlist(lapply(Comps, function(part)all(part > 1)))]
```

You can now use these to make your splits.

```r
lapply(Comps, function(part)split(vect_1, rep(1:length(part), part)))
```

I haven't included the output, because there is a lot of it, even for a vector this short. I also suspect this isn't quite what you want, but it is my best guess.